# Shopify Theme Development - Section and Block development

Tags: themes, shopify, block

Hello Shopify Theme Development Pros,

I am trying to add a block in a section of my theme and although the input block shows up on the screen, when I input type nothing shows up on the actual website.  I have tried defining styles in CSS as well, but no luck.

This is what I have added to the block settings in the liquid file...

```
    {
        "type": "text",
        "id": "review_title",
        "label": "Review Heading",
        "default": "Enter title here"
    },
```

And this is the html that I added...

```
        <div class="testimonial-heading> {% if section.settings.review_title != blank %} <p> {{ section.settings.review_title | escape }} </p> {% endif %}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using blocks you need to loop them since there are dynamic content that can be added multiply times.

So at the moment you are targeting the settings object and not the blocks `section.settings.review_title`.

In order to list the blocks you need to do the following:

```
{% for block in section.blocks %}
    <div class="testimonial-heading"> 
        {% if block.settings.review_title != blank %} 
            <p> {{ block.settings.review_title | escape }} </p> 
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, @drip.  That’s exactly what I needed to do and it worked perfectly. 


I’m basically trying to make a standard template page that can be slightly altered for unique products. For example:

Page 1: Porsche Panamera 
Page 2: Porsche 911
Page 3: Porsche Boxter

They will all have the same standard description on each page (that will be a uniform template), but I want to make it so that the detail section can be edited for each of the pages by creating a block since there are different nuances for each model. Is there a way to do that?